# Splitting a string into multiple with regex

Tags: php, regex, string, split

I've got a string that looks like

```
john1,steven2,lex66,e1esa2,444e3, and so forth (up to about 200)
```

There can be up to 200 of these. What I need is, every 40 for it to be split up into a new

How would I go by this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
array_chunk(explode(',', $string), 40);
```

Read inside out:

- Split the string at commas, into an array
- Chunk the array every 40 elements

[Live example.](http://3v4l.org/8GugQ)

If you then want it back into a string, do:

```
implode(',', array_chunk(explode(',', $string), 40));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that:

```
preg_match_all('~(?:[^,]+,){0,39}[^,]+~', $str, $matches);
```